# Driving two bell coils from an old phone with 90 V, 20 Hz AC

Tags: telephone

I have an old phone which stopped making calls, but the ringer still worked. I used a phone ring generator that generates  90 V, 20 Hz AC to test this. I want to place this ring generator inside the phone, which meant removing the other components. I assumed the ringer coils would operate when connected directly to the  90 V, 20 Hz AC supply, but this is not the case.

My question: how can I connect the two coils to the 90 V supply so they operate? The original schematic is below, where you can see the two 500 ohm coils. I'm using an Arduino to switch the 90 V supply. The coils are in parallel as shown in the schematic, but I can change this if needed. The schematic also shows the ringer arm, that oscillates between the two coils.

N.B My knowledge of electronics is basic.

[image]

Comment: Why not just connect to L+ and L- and let the phone route the ringing voltage to the bell through the capacitor and on-hook contacts as intended?

Comment: The bell coils are in series, not in parallel as you suggest. The 1 uF capacitor is also in series with the coils, and is probably needed to form a resonant circuit with the coils so you get a strong ring. Try that.

Comment: @Transistor I removed the components as I wanted to make space for the other electronics (the Arduino, battery etc.)

Comment: @MarkLeavitt Apologies, they are in series (I meant I could change to parallel if required). I tried adding the 1 uF capacitor in series but that made no difference. As far as I understand, the only purpose of the capacitor is to allow the AC current to pass through while allowing the DC current to operate the other circuitry (as the phone line supplies both DC and AC).

Comment: @MarkLeavitt  that would require over 500H inductance, so no it's not a resonant circuit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you bypass the capacitor you only need about 12V to operate the ringer as a bridge tied load.

The coils are shown in series, not parallel. If you convert the ringer from series to parallel you only need half that.

If you really want to use the 90V ringer supply just connect the two coils and the 1uF capacitor in series across the ringer supply output.